# Use "StartWith" When linking tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to link 2 tables in my database. I was wondering if there is a way to link the tables like this:

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode FROM dbo.Items AS T0
LEFT JOIN dbo.Decoder AS T1
ON T0.ItemCode STARTSWITH T1.Prefix
```

I know how to use `LIKE` in the `WHERE` statement but I need it in the `JOIN` Side of the query. I cannot use `LEFT` because the prefix Length isn't fix and can be either 2,3 or 4

How can I use this in the `FROM` Statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using `PATINDEX`:

```
Select 
    T0.ItemCode 
From 
    dbo.Items AS T0 Left Join dbo.Decoder AS T1 
       ON PATINDEX(T1.Prefix + '%', T0.ItemCode) <> 0
```

[Here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) you might find more information about using this function.

Comment: I'm really glad it helped. Regards.